# How to sort by date but group on a certain column value SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table that looks like this.

```
my_id |    date
-------------------  
  1   | 2013-04-01
  1   | 2013-04-02
  2   | 2013-04-03
  1   | 2013-04-04
  3   | 2013-04-05
  2   | 2013-04-06
```

I would like a SQL query that gives this result.

```
my_id |    date
-------------------  
  2   | 2013-04-06
  2   | 2013-04-03
  3   | 2013-04-05
  1   | 2013-04-04
  1   | 2013-04-02
  1   | 2013-04-01
```

So I want all with the same my_id to be together with date descending order. And the groups of my_id's should be sorted on date descending based on the latest date in the groups.

It is like a threaded conversation you could say, were my_id is the conversation id and the date is the dates of the posts to that conversation. So when showing in a list the conversation with the most recent post should be on top.

Follow up question
If my_id is NULL they should not be grouped together but still sorted by date. This would be if they are not part of a conversation for example.

```
my_id |    date
-------------------  
  1   | 2013-04-01
  1   | 2013-04-02
  2   | 2013-04-03
  1   | 2013-04-04
 NULL | 2013-04-05
  2   | 2013-04-06
 NULL | 2013-04-07
```

The table above would then be like this

```
my_id |    date
-------------------  
 NUll | 2013-04-07
  2   | 2013-04-06
  2   | 2013-04-03
 NULL | 2013-04-05
  1   | 2013-04-04
  1   | 2013-04-02
  1   | 2013-04-01
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT A.my_id, A.YourDate
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT my_id, MAX(YourDate) MaxDate
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY my_id) B
    ON A.my_id = B.my_id
ORDER BY B.MaxDate DESC, A.YourDate DESC
```

**UPDATED**

Not sure if this is what you want with the `NULL` values, but anyway:

```
SELECT A.my_id, A.YourDate
FROM YourTable A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT my_id, MAX(YourDate) MaxDate
            FROM YourTable
            WHERE my_id IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY my_id) B
    ON A.my_id = B.my_id
ORDER BY COALESCE(B.MaxDate,A.YourDate) DESC, A.YourDate DESC
```

Comment: Cool that worked. A follow up question then :) Lets say that my_id can be NULL (posts not part of a conversation) they should then be sorted by date as well but not group together. Would that be possible?

Comment: @Wox Updated my answer, though I'm not exactly sure if this is what you wanted

Comment: Hey, I tried it but it did not really work, it put the rows with NULL id last in the result. I updated my original post to explain better. Thanks alot for your help btw!